# pandas read_excel with multiindex and parse_date; how?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date, multi-index

I am trying to use pandas read_excel to read an excel file with two header rows, and a column which contains dates. I'm trying to use the parse_dates feature to specify the date column to parse, but I'm running into some trouble, code is basically;

```
dateColNms= [('start_date', '(*)Start')]
df = pd.read_excel(fileName,  sheet_name = sheetNm, skiprows=0, header= [0,1], parse_dates = dateColNms)
```

The code throws an error;

```
KeyError: '(*)Start'
```

I've tried variants of specifying the date column names, but none seem to work. Anyone have any pointers? Thanks, Weh.

Comment: can you create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? How does your excel file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you do not have a column with this name '(*)Start'. Try reading excel file with parse_date='start_date' to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. I did try using that before posting my question and it works as expected. Below is a snapshot of the specific header column.
Regards, Weh

[header snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukp0J.png)